# I added a new Library which was downloaded fro github and import with my project in android?

Tags: android

First i was created a folder to right click on my rootProject and create a direcotry(name library) and then i paste my downloaded library into library directory

here is my **settings.gradle**

```
include ':app'
include ':libraries:touchView'
```

and then i got to **File->ProjectStructure>+** then dependancy tab and click on**+** select module dependany and select and press ok

here, is my **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domore.loadlibrary"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile project(':libraries:touchView')
}
```

for few second my build.gradle file is **sync** after it gave me an error which is listed below

```
configuration with the name 'default' not found
```

i also seen this video on youtube
**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MyBO9z7ojk**

please, helm me to solve this problem
[image: this is my project structure]

Comment: Since your library name is `library`,why `:library:touchView` existed in `settings.xml`

Comment: ok i understand you mean why this is default is added??

Comment: i am new in android so i don't know but according to above youtube link i did it.

Comment: hello,sir I hope you understand what i am trying to say?

Comment: Can you provide a screencap for your project structor?

Comment: i have re-Edit my post please, check it

Comment: Can you post whole error?

Comment: Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.